# Are there any Ebook libraries in Canada

Tags: library, canada, loan

Are there any programs that allow library books to be checked out, as ebooks, specifically in Canada?

*NOTE: Based on this [meta post](https://ebooks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168/should-this-question-be-split) and [this question](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/547/can-i-get-an-ebook-from-the-library), I have created this Canadian version of the question.*

Answer (score 4):

That's going to vary by the library system. Not all library chains support lending ebooks. My local library system only started that in the last few years. Even with the system that's available, there's only a finite number of titles available, and a limited number of copies per title. My local library also lends out Kobo e-reader devices.

My local library is the [Greater Victoria Public Library](http://www.gvpl.ca/) (British Columbia). [Landing page](http://www.gvpl.ca/digital-content/ebooks-and-more/) for electronic content. Looks like the [GVPL uses Overdrive](http://overdrive.gvpl.ca/05295DE8-1A1B-4D7A-ABEB-589878FCE9F7/10/50/en/Default.htm) as well.

Answer (score 2):

The [downloadLibrary](http://www.downloadlibrary.ca) (powered by [Overdrive](http://www.overdrive.com/libraries/)) allows me to use my local library card (or anyone with a library card to certain Southern Ontario libraries) to access ebooks and put books on hold. Various smart devices and dedicated ereaders are supported.