# Are there any ebook libraries in Germany

Tags: library, source

Are there any programs that allow library books to be checked out, as ebooks, specifically in Germany?

*NOTE: Based on this [meta post](https://ebooks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168/should-this-question-be-split) and [this question](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/547/can-i-get-an-ebook-from-the-library), I have created this German version of the question.*

Comment: Not a real library, but if you have an Amazon Prime account (€50 p/a) in Germany you can borrow Kindle books, but [only when you read them on a Kindle device](https://www.amazon.de/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=200757120).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most libraries in Germany are in my opinion joined with Onleihe. They have a website where you can see which library is connected by clicking on a map to select your Bundesland (Hessen, Bayern, etc.)

http://www.onleihe.net/ihre-onleihe-finden/onleihen-in-deutschland.html